# Kibana 4 configuration for production

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, kibana, kibana-4

I'm trying to deploy Kibana 4 to Azure Websites. I can't use bin/kibanta.bat file since Azure Websites uses `start` script in `package.json` to bootstrap application. I tried to update `package.json start` script to run `bin\kibana.js` file and environment variables in it. After that Azure starts running Kibana server but I'm getting this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ZeroClipboard is not defined (http://kibana-site.azurewebsites.net/index.js?_b=5827:89458)`. Does anyone tried to make Kibana 4 run not using `bin\kibana*` files? Maybe I have to specify additional environment variables?

Comment: Did you get any conclusion how to runt Kibana 4 in Azure?

Comment: Yes I did. Basically I just wrapped Kibana to new node process which starts the Kibana.bat file. Added to files to the Kibana root directory https://gist.github.com/pauliusnorkus/7cf61e5dfda1fc7224f0

Comment: I'm trying to deploy Kibana 4 by doing something similar. I deploy only the bits under src/ to the root of the website, and strip occurrences of "src/" from package.json to make the paths work. This way, bin/kibana.js is run. I don't get the error you're mentioning, and the application seems to get started but the website only returns an HTTP 500.1001 error.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. It does work when making Kibana listen to the port provided by Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is explained here: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2617

It's a bug that was fixed later.